# How to embed vispy graph in PyQt?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt4, pyside, vispy

I'm trying to embed a vispy plot (more specifically, a Vispy SceneCanvas) as a QWidget into PyQt4. I would presume the answer would be something like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import vispy.mpl_plot as plt

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
vispyCanvas=plt.show()[0]
win.setCentralWidget(vispyCanvas)
```

However, when I try this the last line gives me the expected error that vispyCanvas is type `SceneCanvas` and not of type `QWidget`.  When I `print(vispyCanvas)`, it prints out `<Vispy canvas (PyQt4 (qt) backend) at 0x142bcb00L>`, which is why I suspect that it should be possible to treat it or one of its attributes as a QWidget object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
win.setCentralWidget(vispyCanvas.native)
```

As long as vispy is using Qt as its backend, then `Canvas.native` refers to the underlying `QGLWidget`.